# How to populate a ListBox by differencies between two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to populate ListBox by differencies between two columns
i.e. if a cell exists in one column, and doesn't exist in the second one

```
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Set r1 = Range(Sheets(1).Range("B2"), Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set r2 = Range(Sheets(2).Range("B2"), Sheets(2).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each cc In r1.Cells
For Each cell In r2.Cells
If Not cc.Value = cell.Value Then Form1.ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell
Next cc
Form1.Show
```

What I got is endless proccess (sandClock icon).

Comment: How much data do you have in your sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution, which I think achieves the OP requirement

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim d1, d2
    Dim mtch As Boolean

    Set r1 = Range(Sheets(1).Range("B2"), Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set r2 = Range(Sheets(2).Range("B2"), Sheets(2).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    d1 = r1
    d2 = r2

    For i = 1 To UBound(d1)
        mtch = False
        For j = 1 To UBound(d2)
            If d1(i, 1) = d2(j, 1) Then
                mtch = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not mtch Then
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem d1(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    Me.Show
End Sub
```

Note, there are other methods that may be more efficient, but for 1400 rows this populates the list pretty much instantly

Comment: Chris, Thanks for your attention. You're right. I customized the scott's code. And I allready had some code like yours, but without the `Exit For` line, which is the key for the whole solution. BTW, writing Comments (like this one), very often I type `@`+ the first letter of commenter's name(in this case - c - chris), but the name doesn't appear. Sometimes it works. What could be the reason, pls.

Comment: @Alegro  not sure about the @ name thing - you could ask about that on meta.  It would add value to SO if you posted your code as an answer rather than leaving incorrect code as the accepted answer. BTW copying the ranges into arrays before looping will be much faster than looping ranges directly.

Answer (score 0):

The way that your nested loop is working right now is:  for each cc in r1.cells it checks to see if every cell is equal to cc(1) and if not adds it to your list, then continues on to the next cc. so you end up doing 1400x1400 iterations rather than 1400.

What i think you're after is something more like this:

```
    Dim r1 As long, r2 As long
    r1 = Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    r2 = Sheets(2).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    'set looping integer = to the longest column
    if r1>r2 then 
        r3 = r1
    elseif r2>r1 then 
        r3 = r2
    else: r3 = r1 'if equal set to sheet1 column length
    end if
    for i = 1 to r3 'loop through each row at same time for both sheets
        If sheets(1).range("B" & i).Value <> sheets(2).range("B" & i).Value Then Form1.ListBox1.AddItem sheets(2).range("B" & i).Value
    Next i
    Form1.Show
```

Note that I set the loop length to the length of whichever column has the most records

Comment: scott, I tried you code and got one value - 300 times in Listbox1 (the last value in column2). Also, should I declare r3 As Integer ?

Comment: sorry, forgot to switch the r3 to i, and no i would keep r3 as long since integer has a maximum value that could be reached if your data grows

Comment: @Alegro are you sure this works?  Seems to me it only compares rows, so is if nsay `Sheet1!B10 <> Sheet2!B10` item is added even if it equals another row.